# have you traveled to any countries with last 5 years DS-160

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

My wife was filling her DS-160 , and there was question asking if she has travelled any countries in last 5 years, she has travelled to europe in January of 2017 , thats not within last 5 years per se , but 5ish years(more closer to 6), I asked her not to mention it to be correct as it wasnt in exact 5, would this be a problem or was our answer correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is NO. You can provide the details in additional information section (if any), if you want to be upfront about it.